# flask-migrate: how to add a new database

Tags: flask, flask-migrate

I have a flask setup with development & staging environments.
Now I want to add a production environment wit a production database.

I have troubles integrating the new database into flask-migrations.

I did these steps:

- created fresh postgres DB
- ran `db.create_all()` from the flask app
  (resulting in a DB reflecting the latest version of the data model)
- now all flask-migrate commands have errors

> `sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) column "testfield" of relation "customer_feedback" already exists`,

because flask migrate
   seems to think it needs to apply all migrations that have been
   created until today. But they are not necessary because DB is already fully reflecting models.py.

How can I convince flask-migrate to accept the current state as fully migrated?

Or whats the standard workflow for this?

In other words:
I am coming from Django, where the migrate command creates and updates the model if necessary when adding a blank DB. How should it be done with flask?

Comment: It seems to be that flask-migrate/alembic replaces db.create_all(). My issue seems to be connected to the fact that I started using alembic based on some random version of the model.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell flask migrate that db has already been created and all requirements are already fulfilled. Try following command -

flask db stamp head

This will tell flask migrate not to attempt to add anything.